# v-on:keyup & v-model not updating data

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, v-model

I'm trying to simply update a variable in data through a v-model on a text input, currently it's throwing no errors, and not updating the variable. The JS is in script tags under the html, not an imported component.
Any help would be amazing! :)

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#cover',
  data: {
    message: '',
  },
  methods: {
    mirror: function() {
      console.log('mirrored')
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="cover">
  <h1><strong><span id="goldMoney">@{{ message }}</span></h1>

  <div class="mainSearch" id="vueSearch">
    <input 
      type="text" 
      name="mainSearch" 
      placeholder="Whatchya feel like?" 
      v-model="message" 
      id="searchBox"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using vue-cli or just using cdn

Comment: Just the cdn for this page

Comment: Just wrap your html code with an element like this 
<div id="cover">
your html
</div>
you are not added your parent element with id cover

Comment: it is wrapped in <div id="cover"> already

Comment: may be try comment the  html code other than you are shared

Comment: You might have a typo somewhere we can't see. If I run it as you have it, it works.

Comment: And you mention onkeyup but that's not in here.

Comment: i put it as it is into code snippets that run so people can see yours works, here.

Comment: btw, you're missing a `</strong>`. Sometimes HTML errors, if you're building it in something, can get in the way.